# How to access Twitter included data object?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have extracted the following Twitter data using [`Tweepy`](https://www.tweepy.org/). However, I am not able to fetch data from the included data object. I am specifically trying to fetch the URL and description data. I can see from the json_response that both data on URL and description are present.

My data has the following structure:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "attachments": {
                "media_keys": [
                    "3_1376989039262195713"
                ]
            },
            "author_id": "964661980551266304",
            "created_at": "2021-03-30T20:05:45.000Z",
            "id": "1376989044039544836",
            "text": "@RichardGrenell I also want to speak out against this FB group who blocked me (after asking me to invite all my friends) for making the point that this recall not be made a MAGA one. \n\nI didn\u2019t stump on the ground for Trump, I did it for my children."
        },
        {
            "attachments": {
                "media_keys": [
                    "3_1376986160963145736",
                    "3_1376986160988368898",
                    "3_1376986160963198980",
                    "3_1376986160954757129"
                ]
            },
            "author_id": "1000347213145563136",
            "created_at": "2021-03-30T19:54:20.000Z",
            "id": "1376986169704071171",
            "text": "@Bobbrock8013 @irishson19161 @RandPaul It's ok to question the election of Trump, but if you question Biden's win you are a \"domestic terrorist.\" Does the Biden Admin welcome a discussion of opposing views on policies regarding lockdowns, masks and vaccines? Why is Big Tech censoring conservatives? Fascists censor."
        },
        {
            "attachments": {
                "media_keys": [
                    "3_1376961169450221571"
                ]
            },
            "author_id": "328673472",
            "created_at": "2021-03-30T18:15:00.000Z",
            "id": "1376961171841036291",
            "text": "@ByronYork Newsworthy, but Democrats via their minions will likely censor Trump's statement from Twitter, Facebook, CNN, MSNBC, Washington Post, NY Times etc You know our free speech rules now are based on the Democrats' version of what they will ALLOW us Deplorables to say let alone think."
        },
        {
            "author_id": "18774517",
            "created_at": "2021-03-30T10:31:58.000Z",
            "id": "1376844643837566986",
            "text": "RT @BrexitBuster: @EditingMike @LauraHa15799415 I\u2019m old enough to remember when Piers Morgan was Donald J Trump\u2019s number one fanboy. Are yo\u2026"
        },
        {
            "author_id": "52405628",
            "created_at": "2021-03-30T10:30:33.000Z",
            "id": "1376844286646480899",
            "text": "RT @BrexitBuster: @EditingMike @LauraHa15799415 I\u2019m old enough to remember when Piers Morgan was Donald J Trump\u2019s number one fanboy. Are yo\u2026"
        },
        {
            "author_id": "848911132496723969",
            "created_at": "2021-03-30T10:30:11.000Z",
            "id": "1376844194921250818",
            "text": "RT @BrexitBuster: @EditingMike @LauraHa15799415 I\u2019m old enough to remember when Piers Morgan was Donald J Trump\u2019s number one fanboy. Are yo\u2026"
        },
        {
            "attachments": {
                "media_keys": [
                    "3_1376836461601898499",
                    "3_1376836461614542853"
                ]
            },
            "author_id": "848911132496723969",
            "created_at": "2021-03-30T09:59:37.000Z",
            "id": "1376836504308305921",
            "text": "@EditingMike @LauraHa15799415 I\u2019m old enough to remember when Piers Morgan was Donald J Trump\u2019s number one fanboy. Are you?\n\nThen he praised Joe Biden\u2019s speech... until he was offered the chance to pen a vicious hatchet piece for the Daily Mail! Pointing this out earned me a block.\n#shapeshiftingcreep"
        },
        {
            "attachments": {
                "media_keys": [
                    "3_1376821889004363777"
                ]
            },
            "author_id": "31308988",
            "created_at": "2021-03-30T09:01:34.000Z",
            "id": "1376821895811715073",
            "text": "A lady sent this to my messenger right before she blocked me because she was mad I typed the names of Trump's sex assault victims"
        },
        {
            "attachments": {
                "media_keys": [
                    "3_1376704749379145731"
                ]
            },
            "author_id": "198202008",
            "created_at": "2021-03-30T01:16:05.000Z",
            "id": "1376704753145643014",
            "text": "@moondancer34 @MrCrispyMAGA @lonelymilkshake @EFMoriarty @CBSNews Who is this person who blocked me? A MAGA lover? Guess that\u2019s why. But how ironic that he\u2019s a Trump supporter yet a WA fan when Woody is about as liberal as they get. In fact he donated to Hillary\u2019s campaign so she\u2019d win against Trump. Whatever! \ud83d\ude02\ud83e\udd37\u200d\u2640\ufe0f"
        }
    ],
    "includes": {
        "media": [
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376989039262195713",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ExwMPFDUYAEHKn0.jpg"
            },
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376986160963145736",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ExwJnijWUAgfPlb.jpg"
            },
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376986160988368898",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ExwJnipXMAIHmJp.jpg"
            },
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376986160963198980",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ExwJnijXIAQ4F_x.jpg"
            },
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376986160954757129",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ExwJnihWUAkr8bi.jpg"
            },
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376961169450221571",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Exvy416WQAMRlO0.jpg"
            },
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376836461601898499",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ExuBd4-WQAMgTTR.jpg"
            },
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376836461614542853",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ExuBd5BXMAU2-p_.jpg"
            },
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376821889004363777",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ext0Np0WYAEUBXy.jpg"
            },
            {
                "media_key": "3_1376704749379145731",
                "type": "photo",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ExsJrOtWUAMgVxk.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "created_at": "2018-02-17T00:45:13.000Z",
                "description": "Congressional Candidate for CA-28 Proud Angeleno/Catholic/Californio by marriage Localist\u2022Centrist\u2022Pragmatist\u2022Realist",
                "id": "964661980551266304",
                "name": "Beatrice Cardenas",
                "username": "RealBetyCardens"
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2018-05-26T12:05:35.000Z",
                "description": "Following President Trump .... KAG 2020 \ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8",
                "id": "1000347213145563136",
                "name": "Joseph Fong",
                "username": "JosephEugeneFo1"
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2011-07-03T20:29:43.000Z",
                "description": "Husband, Dad, Granddad, Christian,Army MP Sgt vet, I.U. grad, former banker & retired City Finance Director, Reagan guy. Cancer survivor. \u271d\ufe0f\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8",
                "id": "328673472",
                "name": "Steve B",
                "username": "Stevebfrs"
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2009-01-08T19:06:29.000Z",
                "description": "a younger Victor Meldrew but interesting - I hope - nice sometimes !",
                "id": "18774517",
                "name": "NORBET",
                "username": "NORBET"
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2009-06-30T14:17:41.000Z",
                "description": "Tanglewood and Gretsch",
                "id": "52405628",
                "name": "FSociety Tom \ud83c\uddea\ud83c\uddfa #FBPE ANTIFA #RESIST #FBPPR #BLM",
                "username": "thebdaman"
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2017-04-03T14:52:40.000Z",
                "description": "We are the Remain Resistance... popping Brexit bubbles one at a time. Mostly sarcasm, occasionally deadly serious. Love the UK & the EU. Detest racism & Nazis.",
                "id": "848911132496723969",
                "name": "Brexit Buster",
                "username": "BrexitBuster"
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2009-04-15T02:18:58.000Z",
                "description": "No DMs !!! \ud83c\udf0a \ud83c\udf0a\nBLM ,Trans lives matter, LGBT \ud83c\udf08\nAlly of all marginalized",
                "id": "31308988",
                "name": "Stephy Pachuco (Her, She) \ud83c\udf0a\ud83c\udf0a",
                "username": "Stephaniespc"
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2010-10-03T16:56:45.000Z",
                "description": "How'd you know I was looking at you if you weren't looking at me? \ud83d\udde3Mike Patton \u2615\ufe0fCoffee \ud83d\ude0eWeekends \ud83c\udf0aPolitics \ud83d\ude0dNYC \ud83e\udd96Museum Employee",
                "id": "198202008",
                "name": "Patti\ud83d\uddfd",
                "username": "PattiFromNYC"
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta": {
        "newest_id": "1376989044039544836",
        "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fosqtjm19orv2gber5hh7b0fu7uem5",
        "oldest_id": "1376704753145643014",
        "result_count": 9
    }
}
```

I can successfully fetch the data from the data object which is 'id', 'text', 'created_at', and 'author_id' using the following code. However, the code does not retrieve the 'URL' and 'description' data from the included object which leaves me with two empty columns.

```
# Create file
csvFile = open("data.csv", "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

# Create headers for the data
csvWriter.writerow(
    ['author id', 'created_at', 'id', 'tweet', 'bio', 'image_url'])
csvFile.close()


def append_to_csv(json_response, fileName):
    # A counter variable
    counter = 0

    # Open OR create the target CSV file
    csvFile = open(fileName, "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

    # Loop through each tweet
    for tweet in json_response['data']:

        # We will create a variable for each since some of the keys might not exist for some tweets
        # So we will account for that

        # 1. Author ID
        author_id = tweet['author_id']

        # 2. Time created
        created_at = dateutil.parser.parse(tweet['created_at'])

        # 3. Tweet ID
        tweet_id = tweet['id']

        # 4. Tweet text
        text = tweet['text']

        # 5. description
        if('description' in tweet):
            bio = tweet['users']['description']
        else:
            bio = " "

        # 6. image url
        if ('url' in tweet):
            image_url = tweet['media']['url']
        else:
            image_url = " "

        # Assemble all data in a list
        res = [author_id, created_at, tweet_id, text, bio, image_url]

        # Append the result to the CSV file
        csvWriter.writerow(res)
        counter += 1

# When done, close the CSV file
csvFile.close()

# Print the number of tweets for this iteration
print("# of Tweets added from this response: ", counter)
```

[image: output in a csv format]

Comment: simple reason: those two elements are not in `data`! look again at the data structure.

Comment: Correct! The url and description elements are in the includes object. The problem is I do not know how to access the includes object.

Comment: this might work for the URLs: `for element in json_response['includes']['media']:`

Comment: Thank you! While your suggestion does retrieve the URL's it leaves out all tweets that do not contain a URL and a bio. For the bio I now use                  ```for dics in json_response['includes']['users']: # 5. description if('description' in dics): bio = dics['description'] else: bio = " " for element in json_response['includes']['media']: # 6. image url if ('url' in element): image_url = element['url'] else: image_url = " "
```